# Sending emails for new user in Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a trial account for Microsoft Azure. In Azure Active Directory, I'm trying to create a new user. Is there any way to notify this user via e-mail? Is there any way to send the email to user from Azure AD?

Comment: how your scenario falls into AD B2C?

Comment: Not via the portal, you'd need to implement it yourself. With guest users, they do get an email.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you create new guest users, they will be notified with e-mail. If you [add tenant users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory) from the portal, they will have no email association.

[image]

Reference:

[What is guest user in Azure AD?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/what-is-b2b)

Comment: This is wrong - if you add a new user, it won't automatically send an e-mail to them, which is mindblowing